# how to solve this error {Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]}?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, eclipse

The error message is attached here! I am using spring in eclipse, I tried to retrieve data from DB (MySQL). I used apache tomcat server,mysql connector 5.1

[image: Error]

Comment: "The error message is attached here!" no, it isn't. By reading your title: check your logs for why it doesn't start, and fix the issue

Comment: When you want to present such info in SO paste the text, not image

Comment: Have you gone through what it's saying in the Description part?

Answer (score 0):

change your Tomcat port number...because it already in use.
8080 to something like(8181)